# Returning specific number in C# in a varchar field

Tags: c#, .net

Consider this call:

```
results = db.Students.Where(x => x.Code == current_search);
```

I'd like to be able to get results only for exact number. If I search for `639` it also returns other numbers that contain `639`, for example `1639`. The field contains text strings, so it cannot be used as an integer field.

How can I return just the single number that is being looked for? Presumably I require some sort of regex, but can it be inserted here or will code break?

Comment: This will give only the matching value not as you explained

Comment: Can you provide some sample codes?

Comment: That is not how `Where` works. This will only return exact matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I return just the single number that is being looked for?

Probably you need to rethink the way you are storing your data.

> Presumably I require some sort of regex, but can it be inserted here
>   or will code break?

You won't be able to add the regex to the linq as it cannot be converted to SQL. The closest approach i see here is to get the filtered data first using Contains.

```
 results = db.Students.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(current_search));
```

And then further filter the resultset based on your regex.

By the way x.Code == current_search will get the exact match.

Comment: How would I further filter the resultset? This is what I'm struggling to work out.

Comment: Write your regex to find the exact match you want and then apply that on the ressultset.